# Quickly packaging errors

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I'm having some trouble packaging my Quickly (Python/GTK) app. Creating and packaging a new app (created using `quickly create test` and `cd test; quickly package`) works just fine, but the actual app that I've developed fails to get packaged. Here's the log:

```
...........
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
ERROR: Python module helpers not found
ERROR: Python module ubermessageconfig not found
ERROR: Python module Builder not found
ERROR: Python module Window not found
----------------------------------
```

However, these modules do exist in `app/app_lib`. What's causing the errors, then?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Is 'app' the actual name of your application?

Comment: Not really. Doesn't clash with an already-installed package if that's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the reason:

Turns out, Quickly scans your python code to generate a list of dependencies. If you have half-written modules with syntax errors, `quickly package` will fail (*even if you haven't imported the offending modules anywhere.*)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you probably should be using relative imports like "from . helpers import XXX"  (note the dot)

That prevents quickly from being confused when it tries to find the package that the import belongs to (it knows to ignore explicitly relative imports).

Comment: I am, and it still doesn't work.