# "Python module helpers not found" error when using Quickly

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickly packaging errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152685/quickly-packaging-errors)

I am here asking why quickly is displaying this:

```
ERROR: Python module helpers not found
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]:
```

I am unsure whether I should continue or not, and I have been unable to find someone who has had similar problems.

This error occurred when I ran `quickly submitubuntu`

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciatd :).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179429/debain-package-wont-build-as-its-claiming-it-cant-find-any-of-the-modules

Comment: Yeah, I ignored it and it successfully built, but I was uncertain if I caused instability or potentially opened an exploit lol.

Comment: Looks like bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/+bug/746565, which should be fixed in python-distutils-extra (2.26-2ubuntu0.2). If you are running a newer version of python-distutils-extra you should probably report this as a bug.